# Neither here nor there

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I am neither here nor there

perhaps I belong to nowhere

I am just a part of a day

if you analyze anyway

I am a part of yesterday

and also a part of today

I am a part of today and

I would be part of tomorrow

I would be prominent with a celebration

for many during an annual transition

Got who I am ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is

> Midnight

I am neither here nor there; perhaps I belong to nowhere

> Midnight is a time, not a place

I am just a part of a day, if you analyze anyway

> Midnight is part of a day cycle, but only if you're being technical, since it's really part of the night

I am a part of yesterday and also a part of today; I am a part of today and I would be part of tomorrow

> Midnight is "part of" the day before it and after it.

I would be of prominent with a celebration for many during an annual transition

> Midnight is the key moment of New Year's Day, the annual transition

Comment: Well done @benzene, too quick !